# Image doesn't change size with div container / window

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, image-size

So I'm trying to get some images in my sidebar but they don't want to change size with container / window.

If i resize my window, the image gets under the middle area.

[Link to preview my website](http://blueberry.bplaced.net/)

```
body{ background: grey }
#container{ width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center }
#sidebar{ margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; width: 5%; height: 100%; background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 ); border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #333 }
#interface{ display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; width: 94%; height: 100%; background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 ); border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #333 }

#icon_1{ max-width: 100%; max-height: 100% }
```

Comment: There is no sidebar in your website...

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to be linking to anything but an image on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on your CSS:

```
#icon_1 img {
   width:100%;
}
```

You are setting `width` values for containers but not for the `img` so it displays in full size.

Or better to get all Icon img at one selector:

```
#sidebar img {
   width:100%;
}
```